# Add new properties into google search console without user interactions

Tags: node.js, google-apis-explorer, google-search-console

Hi i have a application which created sub-domains dynamically and when a sub-domain is created i want to add website to google search console and ask google to index this site using sitemap. I am using node.js application and i want to do this in the backend with out any user interations.

```
    const {google} = require('googleapis');

    const webmasters = google.webmasters({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: {myApiKey},
    })

module.exports.getListOfSites = () => {
    let listSitesPromise = webmasters.sites.list({});
    listSitesPromise.then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

This give error

> 401 Login Requried

is there a way to skip authentication and directly add these sites to google search console account.

My whole purpose is to get my sites indexed if there is another method please suggest

Thanks

Comment: You can use package - selenium-webdriver for creating logging browser automation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible u need atleast one user to login, If u want to add all the properties to your own account u can use refresh token from your own account to do so